# Custom UI element containing several TextViews

Tags: android, view, textview

Right now I'm trying to figure out how to create a custom UI component, say custom view. I have a ListView and I want to be able to add elements that contain three TextViews but are atomic, so to speak and have a defined layout. I'm really not sure how to do this and the only idea I have are custom views. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Will your customView be an item of the listView ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you don't need to follow the `CustomView` road. You can customize how you want your ListView's *row* look like. You can add images, multiple textView and whatever you want.

[Here is a good tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) that make the list row look like this: [image]

Comment: Wow that is an amazing answer. Can I add rows on the go programatically?

Comment: You mean by adding rows `more TextViews` ?

Comment: I mean, using the above example, adding more songs to the list.

Comment: Sure you can. This draw illustrate how _a single row_ in your list will look like. You can add as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You can easily accomplish this with a SimpleCursorAdapter if your data is in a cursor.

Use the following:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.customview,cursor, from_columns, to_customviewfields)
```

and then set the adapter to the listview:

```
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```